# How to read and display data from XML for every 30 seconds using JQUERY AJAX and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I am a beginner would be great if someone help me on this.

I need to read and display data (HTML / PHP page) from XML for every 30 seconds.

**XML FILE :**

```
<MAINData>
  <LiveData>
   <Field no="1">ENG ODI</Field>
   <Field no="2">ENG</Field>
   <Field no="3">IND ODI</Field>
   <Field no="4">IND</Field>
   <Field no="5">STRAUSS</Field>
   <Field no="6">PIETERSEN</Field>
   <Field no="7">TROTT</Field>
   <Field no="8">BELL</Field>
   <Field no="9">COLLINGWOOD</Field>
   <Field no="10">PRIOR</Field>
   <Field no="11">YARDY</Field>
   <Field no="12">BRESNAN</Field>
   <Field no="13">SWANN</Field>
   <Field no="14">SHAHZAD</Field>
   <Field no="15">ANDERSON</Field>
   <Field no="16">LBW B KHAN</Field>
   <Field no="17">C AND B PATEL</Field>
   <Field no="18">LBW B CHAWLA</Field>
   <Field no="19">C KOHLI B KHAN</Field>
  </LiveData>
</MAINData>
```

Here is my HTML File :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    

<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<script type="text/javascript">


  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "LiveData.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
            $xml = $(xmlDoc);
            $xml.find('Field[no="1"]').each(function () {
            $("#news-container").append($(this).text() + "<br />");
            
        }
        );
    }
});



  
</script>
</head>
 

<body>
 
  <div class="wrap" id="news-container">
      
      
  </div>
  
 
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to fetch specific details from the XML file and display it in the html page. Also another thing is I need to fetch this for every 30 seconds without refreshing the page.

Comment: You need to read about `long polling` https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ajax request you specified that the data will be xml, in which case you will get back an xml document in your success handler, therefore do not call `$.parseXML`.
Getting the data every 30 seconds is just a matter of calling setTimer or setTimeout setting the timeout to 30 seconds

```js
function getData(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "LiveData.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
            $xml = $(xml);
            $xml.find('Field[no="1"]').each(function () {
              $("#news-container").append($(this).text() + "<br />");

            });
    },
    complete: function(){
        setTimeout(getData, 30000);
    }
  });
}

getData();
```

Comment: great that worked well for me. If I need to get 8 data simultaneously do I need to write like this 

success: function (xml) {
            $xml = $(xml);
            $xml.find('Field[no="1"]').each(function () {
              $("#news-container").append($(this).text() + "<br />");
            });
 $xml.find('Field[no="5"]').each(function () {
              $("#news-container").append($(this).text() + "<br />");
            });
 $xml.find('Field[no="121"]').each(function () {
              $("#news-container").append($(this).text() + "<br />");
            });
    },
is it correct